# How to show countDown timer in Android Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I wanna show a count Down timer in Android Notification.
for example: a Call will be closed after 30s. And I wanna show count down 30, 29 in Notification.
How to realize this feature, and How to use setChronometerCountDown(boolean) of Notification builder?